# Action changes state of all values instead of just particular ones

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I am trying to rewrite my application (weather check application) from standard React state approach into Redux based one. I encountered problem with changing state. In pure React by lanuching this.setState() I was changing only the piece I was passing as an argument in this method. In Redux it seems to change the entire state object even though I pass only part of the entire state, but probably I am doing something wrong.

Here you can see how state transforms when I trigger my action:
[image]

In my example I am trying to set coordinates states (lattitude and longtitude) when clicking the button. Tried several things - I thought that perhaps passing state = [] in reducer function clears out the entire state but I cannot get rid of it as application crashes.

I have 3 reducers: first for geolocation coords, second for weather details and last one for handling loading spinner to be displayed or not

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
    weather: weatherReducer,
    coords: coordsReducer,
    loading: loadingReducer
})
```

Then I have store with initial states as following:

```
const store = createStore(reducers, {
    weather: [{ temperature: "", humidity: "", windSpeed: "", pressure: "", pollution: "", date: "" }],
    coords: { lat: null, lng: null },
    loading: { loading: false }
}, allStoreEnhancers);
```

Not sure if splitting them all into 3 parts is good but I believe so (feel free to point out if I am wrong)

coordsReducer.js:

```
export default function weatherReducer(state = [], { type, payload }) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'updateCoords':
            return payload
        case 'clearCoords':
            return payload
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

and coordsActions.js (simply set coords or clear them out)

```
export function updateCoords(lat = 0, lng = 0) {
    return {
        type: 'updateCoords',
        payload: {
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
        }
    }
}

export function clearCoords() {
    return {
        type: 'clearCoords',
        payload: {
            lat: null,
            lng: null
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I need few things:
1. Opinion if the way I splitted my state and action and reducers makes sense
2. How to change state of single properties instead of changing entire state object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have to pass in the previous state when you are setting new properties. You can do this easily with the spread operator.

```
export default function weatherReducer(state = [], { type, payload }) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'updateCoords':
           return {
            ...state,
            lat: payload.lat,
            lng: payload. lng
         }
        case 'clearCoords':
            return {
             ...state,
            lat: null,
            lng: null
         }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

and you can set the values you want to update individually.